# $H^1(SO(2),T(2))$, or finding all subgroups of the group of motions of the plane which are complementary to the translation subgroup

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology

My question is motivated by [this part](https://books.google.hu/books?id=-eqnxqR3oZsC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22a+necessary+condition+for+these+to+form+a+subgroup+is+the+following+relation:%22&source=bl&ots=bRKerOfyBy&sig=ACfU3U3zGSjnQroL6EBPVuMzretmi1d6RA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEtrac45fiAhXKG5oKHc8DCekQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20necessary%20condition%20for%20these%20to%20form%20a%20subgroup%20is%20the%20following%20relation%3A%22&f=false) of 'Basic Notions of Algebra' from Igor R. Shafarevich. He mentions the  group of motions of the plane in the following context.

Let denote $SE(2)$ the 2-dimensional special [Euclidean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group), $T(2)\subseteq SE(2)$ the translation subgroup of it, $G=SE(2)/T(2)$, and $G'\subseteq SE(2)$ the group of rotations around some fixed point (call it 'origin'). We know that $G'\cong SE(2)/T(2)\cong SO(2)$. We also know that $G'$ is a complementary subgroup of $T(2)$, and it is the image of a section $s: G\to SE(2)$ of the bundle $\pi:SE(2)\to G$. Every other section $s'$ can be written in the form

$$s'(g)=f(g)s(g)\label{a}\tag{1}$$

where $f$ is a function $G\to T(2)$. According Shafarevich, a necessary condition for a section $s'$ defined by $f$ to be a subgroup is 
$$f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)g_1(f(g_2))\label{b}\tag{2}$$
where  $$g_1(f(g_2)):=\gamma f(g_2) \gamma^{-1}\label{c}\tag{3}$$
with any $\gamma\in g_1$, e.g. $\gamma =s(g_1)$ (the result doesn't depend on the choice). We call such $f$ functions *1-cocycles*. According to Shafarevich, there is always a 'trivial' choice of $f$, which results in 
$$s'(g)= f(g)s(g)=as(g)a^{-1}\label{d}\tag{4}$$ 
with an $a\in T(2)$, that is,
$$f(g) = as(g)a^{-1}s(g)^{-1}\label{e}\tag{5}$$
We can check that this $f$ satisfies ($\ref{b}$). These cocycles are called *1-coboundaries*.

By some intuition (regarding the motion of the Moon around the Earth) I've found that taking any $a\in T(2)$

$$s'(g) = c_{s(g)}(as(g)a^{-1})=s(g)as(g)a^{-1}s(g)^{-1}\label{f}\tag{6}$$

is also a section with image forming a subgroup of $SE(2)$ complementary to $T(2)$. The 1-cocycle belonging to this $s'$ is
$$f(g) = c_{s(g)}(as(g)a^{-1})s(g)^{-1}\label{g}\tag{7}$$
(where $c_{s(g)}$ means conjugation by $s(g)$).

**My question**: How can we find all cocycles, i.e. all functions $f$ that satisfies ($\ref{b}$). In other words, how can we find all complementary subgroups to $T(2)$ in $SE(2)$?

Comment: Are you trying to find all cocycles or all continuous cocycles? Accordingly, all subgroups or all Lie subgroups?

Comment: @MoisheKohan  For the time being, I would be pleased with the Lie subgroups.

Comment: Hint: Every such subgroup is a group of rotations fixing some point in the plane.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why?

Comment: If $R_1, R_2$ two rotations with different centers then their commutator $[R_1, R_2]$ is a translation. Hence, your subgroup cannot contain such pairs of rotations. Since your subgroup has to map onto $SO(2)$ (under the linear part homomorphism), it has to equal a group of rotations with a fixed center.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see. Then all cocycle is a coboundary, and all are continuous, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, a posteriori.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Then this is the answer on my question. Don't you want to write it as an official answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was to describe all subgroups $G<SE(e)$ (the group of orientation-preserving isometries of $E^2$) whose linear part equals $SO(2)$ and whose intersection with ${\mathbb R}^2$ (the subgroup of translations of $SE(2)$) is trivial. The answer is that all such subgroups have the form $K_x$, the group of rotations fixing $x\in E^2$.

In order to prove that these are the only subgroups, observe that if $R_1, R_2$ are two rotations fixing distinct points in $E^2$ then their commutator $[R_1,R_2]$ is a nontrivial translation (this is a simple computation which involves composition of four affine isometries). Therefore, a subgroup  $G<SE(e)$ which has trivial intersection with ${\mathbb R}^2$ contains no rotations around distinct points in $E^2$. Hence, such $G$ is contained in one of the groups $K_x$. On the other hand, since the map to the linear part is an isomorphism $K_x\to SO(2)$, we conclude that $G=K_x$. qed